# Convert "\xF0\x9D\x96\xA7\xF0\x9D" to "normal" string in Python

Tags: python, utf-8, character-encoding

(Note, I'm not 100% certain how strings are encoded, the difference between different encoding-schemes etc. thus I might ask a stupid question here. I'm using VScode as IDE and Python 3.8.1)

I ran into a problem today, where a customer have sent us an email. I have pulled the email, from Zendesk's API and wanted to store it in our MySQL database. I got this `incorrect string value '\xF0\x9D\x96\xA7\xF0\x9D'` error when pushing, which was odd since the email-body was just plain text like `Hello - where is my package?` (in another language). After a while I noticed all the letters did not look like "ordinary string letters" and it turned out that the `Hello` in the email was not equal to `"Hello"` i.e `email_body[:5]=="Hello"` was false (maybe some weird font was used in the email?). Encoding the body showed, that the body indeed started with `\xF0\x9D\x96\xA7\xF0\x9D` and not "Hello"

The issue is, as show above, that `"Hello"` in the mail is not equal to "ordinary" `"Hello"` thus I'm not able to compare strings, doing string-manipulation etc.

Is there a way to convert the "Hello" I got from the email-body to ordinary string, such that the two "Hello"-strings are equal again?

Comment: You could use the [`unidecode` module](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/) but I suspect that's not what you really want.

Comment: If that can convert emails encoded in a weird way (maybe because of the font?) then I'm certainly open for suggestions

Comment: I'm pretty sure your problem has nothing to do with the font either.

Comment: How do I then convert the "weird" looking `Hello` to an "ordinary" `Hello`?

Comment: You probably have multiple problems.  That doesn't look like a Unicode string, it looks like a byte string - and you won't get anywhere until you know what encoding it's in.

Comment: As @Mark Ransom says we need to see original text also is there any special character before the Hello string.

Comment: I suggest you to loop through all codec from https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings to see if you can get "Hello". For example, try `b'\xF0\x9D\x96\xA7\xF0\x9D'.decode(cp737)`

Comment: The first 4 bytes are U+15AD7 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL H encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: That sounds valid @Mark Tolonen . Feel free to post that as an answer along with how that was figured, then I should be able to take it from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the string starts with the Unicode character U+15AD7 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL H which looks like a normal H but is a different character.

The error message from MySQL probably results from your MySQL table using the `utf8` encoding instead of `utf8mb4`. The latter is required to store Unicode characters beyond the basic multilingual plane (codepoints larger than 0xFFFF).

You can convert U+15AD7 MATHEMATICAL SANS-SERIF CAPITAL H to U+0048 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER H by normalizing with a compatibility normalization form like NFKC but this won't solve the underlying database issue:

```
import unicodedata
s = b"\xF0\x9D\x96\xA7".decode()
n = unicodedata.normalize('NFKC', s)
print(n, '%04x'%ord(n))  # Should print "H 0048"
```

Comment: actually, it just prints "H"